# problem with looping a list, list index out of range

Tags: python, list, loops, int

What I'm doing wrong?

I get the following error:

IndexError: list index out of range

```
a = []
for x in range(0,3):
    print("Enter a")
    aa = int(input())
    if 0<aa and aa<=100:              
        a[x] = aa
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly. You initialize an empty list, then try to index into it: `a[x] = aa` so of course, there will be an `IndexError`

Comment: “a” is an empty list. Seems like a legit bug: mean to put something in the list *first*? (Unlike JS, Python cannot “grow” a list using the index operator.)

Comment: you are trying to access the index which does not exist in the list yet. For example aa= 5 and a[0]= aa, but list 'a' length is still zero, so index 0 doesn't exist. This way you can update the list but cant add to it.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what the problem is